# How does the window.onload function work?

Tags: javascript

I don't know javascript well. So may be stupid question here:

Suppose, we can add a prototype or say property to the window object like

```
window.something = function(){..}
```

or,

```
window.something = "somestring"
```

But how `window.onload = function(){....}` is not creating onload function but assigning it to run when loaded....

And if the onload is built-in function then `window.onload = function(){...}` should override the onload function....?!?!

Comment: Thats correct! This is was the event is made for. It is called at appropriate time.

Comment: The object 'window' has a property 'onload', which is to be invoked when a page is loaded.

Comment: I know that's correct. But wanted to know, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window.onload` property is created by the browser and exists by default.  By default is has a value of `null`.  But, if you assign a function to it (so it contains a valid function instead of `null`), then the browser will call that function when the page resources have finished loading.

Here's a little demo that illustrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7z48j/

Answer (score 1):

That's called by the browser !

window.onload gets fired after the main HTML, all CSS, all images and all other resources have been loaded and rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Many properties of the `window` and `document` object are recognized specially by the browser. In this case, when the `window.onload` property is set, the browser automatically runs the function after loading the document into the browser window.